# Can Flash SWF communicate with Java applet, and vice versa, in any way?

Tags: java, javascript, flash, actionscript-3, applet

I know Flash can use ExternalInterface to call Javascript functions but I don't know if it can call applet also like that. Maybe it can be done by SWF -> JS -> Applet, and back, I don't know. Since I have no idea how to do applets, I would also appreciate at least some pseudo code. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Applets can communicate with JS, and JS can control applets.  See these examples of [Java/JavaScript interaction](http://www.rgagnon.com/topics/java-js.html).

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Sockets.  Your Java applet can open a server socket, probably a HTTP socket, and Flash/Flex can post content to the socket.  Your applet will have to be signed by a known CA to be trusted, but once that's done you can pretty much do what you want.