# install java plugin inside HTML element in ActionScript3

Tags: java, html, actionscript-3, plugins

i have tried to open a link inside HTML element in AS3 , but there is nothing .
in chrome,mozilla will work and open the link because it need a java plugin installed.
can i add java plugin in my Adobe Air to use it in HTML element and open link ?
the link is [Click Here](http://www.aghandoura.com/ARAB100/vm1_asid_264.htm)

Comment: same issue here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18758738/java-plugin-in-a-flex-html-component

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Flash SWF communicate with Java applet, and vice versa, in any way?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032248/can-flash-swf-communicate-with-java-applet-and-vice-versa-in-any-way)