# Java plugin in a Flex HTML component

Tags: java, actionscript-3, apache-flex

Anyone have an idea how to access through HTML component a page that requires Java plugin? I am using this new samsung android camera and I would like to open the link where the camera is streaming the video in a html component. If I make a browser like the one in tour de flex using the html component, it opens the page where the video should be seen. But then how do I access the Java plugin to play it.

Thanks,
David

Comment: It looks like the player uses this applet code to access the video from the camera.<applet code="camsvr05" archive="camsvr05.jar" name="camsvr05" width="650" height="526" title="Java(TM)"><param name="wid" value="640"><param name="hgt" value="480"><param name="rot" value="0"></applet>. I was thinking maybe I could use this Java applet through Flex. Like in this blog:http://tobiaspatton.wordpress.com/2007/08/29/using-a-signed-java-applet-as-a-flex-helper-part-1/#comment-116

Comment: If you want to include additional info; like your above comment, you should edit your question and add the code or other information as part of the question.  Code can be formatted in the question editor by highlighting the code and clicking the curly bracket button. That said; does this HTML page work in the Android browser?  IF not; then it won't work inside a Flash app.  If so, then you may consider trying StageWebView instead of the HTML Component.  [I'm not sure if it'll work, though]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Flash SWF communicate with Java applet, and vice versa, in any way?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032248/can-flash-swf-communicate-with-java-applet-and-vice-versa-in-any-way)